# How to calculate the generators of a list of stabilizer?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, stabilizer-state

Let's say we have a list of stabilizers: {'YZY*', 'XYY*', 'YZYZ', 'Z*Z*', '*XZ*', 'XZX*', 'ZX*Z', 'XZXZ', 'YYX*', 'Z*ZZ'}. Is there any existed formula or function (eg. in qiskit) that can calculate its generators?

Comment: Note that there isn't a single set of generators. It is rather like giving a basis for a subspace ... there are many equivalent ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I'd do it is to write out the stabilizers in a $10\times 8$ matrix in this case (number of rows= number of stabilizers, number of columns is double the number of qubits). For each row, take a stabilizer and write out, for the first 4 columns, if there's an $X$ on a given qubit, and in the last 4 columns, if there's a $Z$ on a given qubit (remember, $Y$ contains both $X$ and $Z$).

Then, I'd simply run row reduction on my matrix (modulo 2). I don't know how to do this in qiskit, but Mathematica has the handy function RowReduce that can work modulo 2.

In essence, you're running Gram-Schmidt asking if each stabilizer in turn can be created as a product of the stabilizers already in your set.

Comment: Thanks! I used your method and did the RowReduce. I got a matrix:

Comment: Yes, you should have a matrix that specifies the (max) 4 stabilizers that generate the given stabilizers. (Note that the result is non-unique).

Comment: Thanks! Here is the matrix that I got
{{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}

It has 5 terms that contain non-zero entry. In my understanding, they correspond to 5 generators: XZXI, IXII, ZIII, IIZI, IIIZ. . But you said the maximum number is 4, right? How can I eliminate them?

Comment: Some of those don't commute. That suggests either your initial "stabilizers" don't commute with each other, or you've made a typo in entering the matrix.

Comment: I got the answer {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience! Could you please check my stabilizer matrix?
I followed your instructions: first 4 columns X and other 4 columns Z. For Y, both are 1 and for I, both are 0. 
RowReduce[{{1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},{1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1}}]

I use this matrix and got my results with 5 generators...

Comment: That's the same matrix I used. You've forgotten to tell it to do the calculation modulo 2. You need RowReduce[M, Modulus -> 2] where M is your matrix.

Comment: I see! I tried and got the same result! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it correct to perform the RREF on the whole matrix? I could see that working for counting how many is in the minimal set or for comparing sets of stabilizers generators, but not for reducing to the minimal set. I'm now thinking that for a symplectic form of an r x 2n sized matrix that you have to perform the same operations on both halves of the matrix -- the X portion and Z portion. If you only reduce the X portion I could see that leaving the matrix w/ generators that don't commute (since some Ys may turn into Zs).

Comment: @AmirEbrahimi Definitely the whole matrix!